# Md size of Bootstrap start from resolution 1200 pixels

Tags: bootstrap-4

Okay, here the first question.

What are you see in the image below?

[image]

If I do believe that I see there are wrote *medium greater than 768 pixels* .Right?

Then why my `2` block takes `12` size of the column when the size of screen equal or less than `1200` pixels and greater `992` pixels?

If you look at my code attentively you see I wrote

`col-lg-8` in `news` class and `col-lg-4` in `posts` class but in `md` I wrote `col-md-12` for both classes they should change started  from `990` pixels

And  less than `1200` pixels it could be `lg` size not `md` size

```css
.news {
    background:cadetblue;
}
.posts {
    background:pink;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="news col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 сol-lg-8 col-xl-8">fdsf
                  
                </div>
                <div class="posts col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">adadad
                   
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: How it possible ? O.o

Comment: You have a encoding error in your syntax. In detail it's the 'c' from 'col-lg-8. In Ansi encoding it's not a 'c', but a 'Ñ'. Just retype 'col-lg-8' and it works fine.

Comment: @DanielBeckmann Thank you .How you know about this encoding issue?

Comment: @Spectr I used the developer console of chrome browser to examine the applied CSS styles. The col-lg-4 was applied, but the col-lg-8 was not. So I removed the class and added it again and that worked ;)

Comment: @DanielBeckmann much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MD tier goes from 991px *down* to 768px. If you want it to stack less than 768px it would be...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="news col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
        fdsf  
        </div>
        <div class="posts col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        adadad   
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/JZFOfWACnj

Also note that the smaller tiers imply the larger breakpoints, unless overridden by a larger tier. This means the markup can be simplified to...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="news col-md-8">
        fdsf  
        </div>
        <div class="posts col-md-4">
        adadad   
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```